# Remove everything except some word from every line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to find a regex solution to keep `&#xA;` and remove other things without breaking the line order. Only some of the lines contains this pattern one or more times. I tried `(?<=&#xA;)(.+)|(.+)(?=&#xA;)|^((?!&#xA;).)*$`, but it only keeps one from each row, although they contain more. For example, I have something like that:

```
The client requires photos of a radioactive world&#xA;Reach the target planet.
The client requires photos.&#xA;&#xA;Reach the target planet.
The client requires photos of a desert world&#xA;Reach the target planet.
The client requires photos of an airless world. Reach the target planet.
The client requires photos of a strange world&#xA;&#xA;Reach the target planet&#xA;Make a quick scan.
```

Expecting exactly this:

```
&#xA;
&#xA;&#xA;
&#xA;

&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;
```

I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capturing group.

```
(.*?)((?:&#xA;){0,})
```

**Details:**

- `(.*?)`: Group1 - matches any characters as few as possible
- `((?:&#xA;){0,})`: Group2 - matches `&#xA;` or not

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ILleMu/1)

Comment: Strangally it doesn't work on notepad. It says n lines changed but I can't see any difference.

Comment: Ok, I just tried on Sublime Text and it worked exactly as I want. Don't know why notepad++ gives such a result. Anyway this will do. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following RegEx to match everything except `&#xA`

```
[^&#xA;\n]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DJP1lD/1/)

Comment: It seems works on my samples. But I tried on 50k lines and it also keeps unnecessery characters. It makes this sentences: "The disturbed region must be accessed by &lt;SPECIAL&gt;Portal&lt;&gt;&#xA;Speak to the inhabitants of the Space Anomaly to learn more" to "&;A&;&;&;&#xA;A"

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to match `&#xA;` and then not consume the match.

Then match all characters except &, and when it does encounter &, assert that it is not directly followed by `#xA;`

**Find what**

```
&#xA;(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^&\r\n]+(?:&(?!#xA;)[^&\r\n]*)*
```

**Replace with:**

Leave empty

**Explanation**

- `#xA;` Match literally
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|` Consume the characters that you want to avoid
- `[^&\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except `&` or a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `&(?!#xA;)` Match & if not directly followed by `#xA;`
  - `[^&\r\n]*` Match 0+ times any char except & or a newline
- `)*` Close the non capture group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZjmCg7/1)

[image]